# Trouble Deserializing Object Pulled from SQS using GSON

Tags: events, amazon-s3, gson, amazon-sqs, typetoken

I have a lambda function the receives an S3Event object when a file is put into an S3 Bucket. When the lambda fails, it goes to a dead letter queue set up in Amazon SQS.

When I pull these messages, this this the body:

```
{
"Records": [
    {
        "eventVersion": "2.1",
        "eventSource": "aws:s3",
        "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
        "eventTime": "d",
        "eventName": "d:Put",
        "userIdentity": {
            "principalId": ""
        },
        "requestParameters": {
            "sourceIPAddress": "2"
        },
        "responseElements": {
            "x-amz-request-id": "",
            "x-amz-id-2": "g"
        },
        "s3": {
            "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
            "configurationId": "",
            "bucket": {
                "name": "",
                "ownerIdentity": {
                    "principalId": ""
                },
                "arn": ""
            },
            "object": {
                "key": "",
                "size": 12502,
                "eTag": "",
                "sequencer": ""
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

That looks quite a bit like the S3Event object which contains a list of S3EventNotification records. I have tried to deserialize it to the S3 Event Object using the following:

```
S3Event event = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create().fromJson(s3EventString, S3Event.class);
```

This results in a null object like so:

```
{"records":null}
```

I noticed in the json return from SQS, the "R" in Records is capitalized. I wasn't sure if that made a difference so I changed it to a lowercase "r" and it throws this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
```

I'm really not sure what type of object this actually is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Strange. Using Jackson it works perfectly so I will use this for now..

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.Message;

private S3Event extractS3Event(Message message){
     ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
     return objectMapper.readValue(message.getBody(), S3Event.class)
}

//Then to get the S3 Details

S3Event event = extractS3Event(message);
S3Entity entity = event.getRecords().get(0).getS3();
String bucketName = entity.getBucket().getName();
String s3Key = entity.getObject().getKey();
```

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/issues/45

Answer (score 0):

Re:`BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING`.

This is because AWS uses JodaTime for EventTime.  You can avoid the issue by removing the field from the JSON text (assuming you do not need it)